# VAR(unsigned long long,TYPEDEF) What does this syntax mean to you? OSEK/VDX

Tags: embedded

I am working on OSEK. I found in the event api configuration file

> typedef VAR(unsigned long long,TYPEDEF)   EventMaskType; //[OSEK_OS_13.5.1]

What does this mean to you? Any idea what is this.

In my view, as  I am working in OSEK, it is something #defined somewhere in some other file.

I only want to know about the syntax being used. How it is resolved.

p.s: Anything you know or hint please answer.

Comment: Did you searched for a `VAR` macro? I suppose it will be expanded in this case simply to `typedef unsigned long long EventMask;`

Comment: @jeb, I searched for it in header files. But surprisingly I found about 1800 matches in 400+ .h and .c files. So, I decided to ask here to get an idea what is going on..

Comment: @user263210 : Well you only need to worry about the header files (and only the ones that define the API), and ultimately only the one "`#define VAR(`" (though a regular expression to account for variable white-space may be needed).  Alternatively any decent IDE will allow you to right-click the symbol and select "Goto Definition..." or similar.  Posting a question on SO is no substitute for learning how to navigate code.

Comment: @user263210 You should be able to tell the compiler to output the preprocessor stage. Then you can see how the macro is replaced

Comment: @Clifford, I am writing in notepad and then compiling and building through DOS prompt. There is a batch file written which I run to build my code with several several files included. I am working on RTOS. If there is an IDE then it will be much easier.
Anyway Thanks for the hint, I found the file its compiler.h and it is defined as: **#define VAR(type, memclass) memclass type**
This is replacing simply with **type** and **memclass** passed to it.

Comment: @jeb, I did not get what you said. I am using GHS compiler. How can I tell this compiler or any other compiler to output the pre-processor stage?

Comment: @user263210 : And presumably `TYPEDEF` is yet another macro?  Regarding pre-processor outout, your compiler documentation will tell you how to generate that. The `-P filename.i` or `-E` (output to stdout) I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax can be entirely obfuscated by the use of C pre-processor macros.  What the compiler sees is the code *after* preprocessing and therefore after expansion of the macro.  So the answer depends entirely on what the macro `VAR()` expands to.

Comment: I knew it but finding it in so much files was a problem, which is now solved.